# can't locate xpath for td scrapyspider

Tags: python, xpath, html-table, scrapy

I am trying to create a spider to get the following information `10, 861, Wednesday` from the `td` and much more for next many `td`. Please see the picture. Thank you so much!!!

[image]

Comment: Please include code as text and not as image.

Comment: put HTML as text, not screenshot. Or add url to question.

Comment: try `"(//td)[3]/text()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all `td` then use `xpath('//td')`

```
import lxml.html

html = '''
<tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$681</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>other</td>
    <td>data</td>
</tr>
'''

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
all_td = soup.xpath('//td')

for td in all_td:
    print(td.text)
```

Result

```
10
$681
Wednesday
other
data
```

If you need only some of `td` then get all and later use index ie `[2]`, or slicing `[2:]`

```
for td in all_td[2:]:
    print(td.text)
```

Result

```
Wednesday
other
data
```

You can get only one using `[3]` directly in xpath `xpath('//td[3]')`

```
import lxml.html

html = '''
<tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$681</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
</tr>
'''

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
date = soup.xpath('//td[3]/text()')[0]

print(date)
```

Result

```
Wednesday
```

Comment: Thank you so much!